# How to not share axes in FacetGrid

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm attempting to plot the KDE each column in a dataframe `df`, with the last column being a boolean with which I plot two hues on each graph, through the use of

```
sns.pairplot(df, hue='last', palette={True: "#FF0000", False: "#0000FF"}, diag_kind='kde')
```

This gives me nice KDEs for all of the columns. However, I don't really care for comparing each column pairwise; I only really want to see how the KDEs differ based on the value of `last`. However, no other method is that elegant. The only other option I've seen is using a `FacetGrid`, but that has the flaw that the axes limits are all the same. I just can't find a nice way to visualize each column and its relation to the last boolean column.

Comment: Since it totally makes sense to have equal axis limits for comparisson, I don't quite understand the problem. Maybe you want to share the code you used to create the FacetGrid and state what you don't like about the result.

Comment: The reason why I don't want nor need equal axes is because I'm looking at each column individually compared. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I just needed to set `sharex` and `sharey` in the `FacetGrid.__init__` to `False`:

```
sns.FacetGrid(data=df.melt(id_vars=['last']), col="variable", hue="last", 
              palette={True: "#FF0000", False: "#0000FF"}, sharex=False, 
              sharey=False, col_wrap=4).map(sns.kdeplot, 'value', shade=True)
```