# In Seaborn's FacetGrid how to adjust the scale of the x axes to the range of available data

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, subplot

I have the following [Seaborn FaceGrid](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html) output:

[image]

generated with a snippet like this:

```
imax = 3

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['x','y','i'])
for i in range(imax):
    # Creating vectors X and Y
    x = np.linspace(0, 1/(2 ** i),101)
    y = x ** x
    df = df.append(pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y, 'i':i}), ignore_index = True)

g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col='i')
g = g.map(sns.lineplot, 'x', 'y')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.show()
```

(See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/halloleo/7083e8324554415235d84523b6ffa2b0) for the full source.)

In the grid I would like the x axes always be adjusted to the available x values for the respective "i". How can I do this?

#### What I have tried

I called `set_xbound` on the `axes` objects:

```
for i,b in enumerate(g.axes[0]):
    b.set_xbound(0, 1/(2 ** i))
```

but this sets the x-scale to `[0,0.25]` for *all* subplots, while I obviously want for the first subplot `[0,1]`, then `[0.5]`  and only for the last subplot `[0,0.25]`.

Comment: Use `sns.relplot`: `sns.relplot(data=df, kind='line', col='i', x=x, y=y, facet_kws={'sharey': False, 'sharex': False})`. There is no need to map `axes` level plots onto a FacetGrid. Tested in `seaborn 0.11.2`.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney How cool is that! Exactly what I need. Would you write it up as an answer, please?

Comment: It's already an answer. I'll just dup it

Comment: Aaah, this over-jealous deduping! I don't think this is a duplicate: Nobody looking for `FaceGrid.map` solution will find this in a thread about `relplot`!

Comment: Is there a way to take the dup tag away (or at least vote for it) and write the answer here?

Comment: What about this one https://stackoverflow.com/q/53490885/7758804

Comment: Also, if I do a google search with _seaborn facetgrid prevent sharex site:stackoverflow.com_, the first duplicate is the first link, because .relplot is a FacetGrid

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney stackoverflow.com/q/53490885/7758804  is definitely closer (and gives me new ideas!).